# Plan a route in prolog without using a list

Tags: recursion, prolog

I have the following prolog knowledge base containing train connections in Europe:

```
connection(paris, barcelona).
connection(barcelona, madrid).
connection(madrid, lisbon).
connection(paris, brussels).
connection(brussels, amsterdam).
connection(amsterdam, hamburg).
connection(hamburg, berlin).
```

I want to create a predicate ride/3 that can draw a route without creating a list. The three arguments should be 1. the starting point 2. the end point 3. the route, which should be a predicate fromTo/2.

An example:

```
?- ride(paris,lisbon,X).
    X = fromTo(paris,barcelona, fromTo(barcelona,madrid,
        fromTo(madrid,lisbon)))
```

I thought the base clause should be something along the lines of this, but that gives me an error.

```
ride(X,Y,go(X,Y):- connection(X,Y)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You have unbalanced parentheses in your code. Is that your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because your base case is missing a parenthesis. Also looking from your expected output the third argument should be `fromTo(X,Y)`.

Your recursive clause should be one that starts from `X`, goes to `Z` and then recursively calls itself but now going from `Z` to `Y`:

```
ride(X, Y, fromTo(X, Y)):-
  connection(X, Y).
ride(X, Y, fromTo(X, Z, Chain)):-
  connection(X, Z),
  ride(Z, Y, Chain).
```

Sample run:

```
?- ride(paris,lisbon,X).
X = fromTo(paris, barcelona, fromTo(barcelona, madrid, fromTo(madrid, lisbon))) ;
false.
```